# Coincidence of linear function and non degenerate bilinear function

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\varphi$ - nondegenerate bilinear function, $\xi$ - linear function. Show that $\exists b\in V$ such that $\forall a\in V$ the following holds $\xi(a)=\varphi(a,b)$.

I have the following idea and I am sure that it should lead to the solution but I don't know how to finish it.

**My approach:** Since $\xi:V\to \mathbb{k}$ is linear function then one can show that $\dim \operatorname{Im}\xi\in \{0,1\}$.

If $\dim \operatorname{Im}\xi=0$ then $\operatorname{Im}\xi=\{0\}$ and it means that $\xi$ is zero linear function. But since $\varphi$ is nondegenerate then right kernel of $\varphi$ is nonempty. In other words, $\exists b\in V$ such that $\forall a\in V$ we have $\varphi(a,b)=0=\xi(a).$ In this case we are done.

But if $\dim \operatorname{Im}\xi=1$ then $\operatorname{Im}\xi=\mathbb{k}$, i.e. $\xi$ is surjective linear functional. Then I am trying somehow to use that $\varphi$ is nondegenerate but don't know how to do it correctly. I have tried some ways but failed.

Can anyone please show how to finish my reasoning, please?

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional?

Comment: @copper.hat, yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $v_k$ be a basis. Let $A_{ij} = \phi(v_i,v_j)$ and $l_j = \xi(v_j)$.

Then $\phi(\sum_j x_j v_j, \sum_i y_i v_i) = x^T Ay$. and
$\xi(\sum_j x_j v_j) = x^T l$.

Since $\phi$ is non degenerate we see that $A$ is invertible.

Choose $y$ such that $Ay=l$, then $\phi(\sum_j x_j v_j, \sum_i y_i v_i) = x^T l = \xi(\sum_j x_j v_j) $.

Letting $b=\sum_i y_i v_i$ we have $\phi(a,b) = \xi(a)$ for all $a$.

Comment: This is really nice! +1

Answer (score 2):

In finite dimensional case nondegenerate bilinear form has invertible matrix in any basis, so:
$$
\xi(a)=A^TV=A^T G G^{-1}V=\phi(a,b)
$$
, where
$$
V_i=\xi(e_i),\;G_{ij}=\phi(e_i,e_j)
$$

If $\mathbf{dim\:im}\:\xi = 1$ then ${V = \mathbf{ker}\:\xi\:\oplus \langle v\rangle}$, and $\exists \:c \in V$ with $\phi(v,c)\neq 0$ and 
$\forall z\in \mathbf{ker}\:\xi:\phi(z,c)=0$.

Let $\{e_1,...,e_{n-1}\}$ be a basis of $\mathbf{ker}\:\xi$, define linear function from $V$ to $\mathbb k^{n-1}$ by
$$\psi:\: a \mapsto \{\phi(e_1,a),...,\phi(e_{n-1},a)\}$$

Then $\mathbf{dim\:ker}\:\psi \ge 1$ for all bilinear functions $\phi$.
So if $c\in \mathbf{ker}\:\psi \land c\neq 0$ then $\phi(v,c)\neq0$ or otherwise $\phi$ would be degenerate, because $\{e_1,...,e_{n-1},v\}$ is a basis of $V$.

Then every $a\in V$ can be expresed as $a=z+\lambda\:v$, where $z\in \mathbf{ker}\:\xi$ and

$$
\xi(a)=\xi(z+\lambda\:v)=\lambda\:\xi(v)=\lambda\:\phi(v,\xi(v)\:c/\phi(v,c))=\phi(z+\lambda\:v,b)=\phi(a,b)
$$

, because $b=\xi(v)\:c/\phi(v,c)\in\mathbf{ker}\:\psi$.

Comment: Could you explain please how did you get such $c\in V$? I am bit confused with this.

Comment: It would be great if you can give some explanation and motivation? Because i was not able to understand nothing about your reasoning

Answer (score 0):

A proof without matrices:
In finite-dimensional case, the mapping $T: V \to V'$ where $T(v) = y: y(v')=\phi(v',v)$ is linear (1), and one-to-one when $\phi$ is nondegenerate (2). Therefore, its range is a subspace of $V'$ isomorphic to $V$, with dimension equal to $\dim V$. Since $\dim V' = \dim V$ when $V$ is finte-dimensional, the described subspace coincides with $V'$. Consequently, $\forall \xi \in V':\exists v\in V: T(v)= \xi: \xi(v')=\phi(v',v).$

(1): $$T(\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2) = y: y(v')= \phi(v', \alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2) = \alpha_1\phi(v',v_1) + \alpha_2\phi(v',v_2) = \alpha_1(T(v_1))(v')+\alpha_2(T(v_2))(v') \Rightarrow T(\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2)=\alpha_1T(v_1)+\alpha_2T(v_2).$$
(2):
$$T(v_1)=T(v_2) \Rightarrow \forall v: \phi(v,v_1)=\phi(v,v_2) \Rightarrow \forall v:\phi(v,v_1-v_2)=\phi(v,v_1)-\phi(v,v_2)=0 \Rightarrow v_1=v_2.$$